# My own VSCode extension only works in the Extension Development Host

Tags: vscode-extensions

My own VSCode extension is working inside the Extension Development Host but does not work when I open VSCode. I have copied my extension folder - named sasm - in the .vscode/extensions folder.

[.vscode/extensions folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ocos.png)

[Content of my sasm extension folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaFrP.png)

When I open a project folder with some .sasm files, VSCode keeps the 'Plain text' mode for these files - and hence no keywords are colored - even though the Extension Development Host manages to do it.

[Extension works in the Extension Dev. Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7VUD.png)

[Extension does not work/is not loaded in a "regular" launch of VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a33z.png)

Comment: Please use the right way to pack up your extension, such as `vsce package`. Never ever copy the folder around.

Comment: @LexLi You're right. This worked beautifully.